# How can I solve the following result?

Tags: python, sql, windows, pyodbc

I have and script the make a select from SQL and returns the value, and the script works with the "code = code + 1" method to make the conditions of the select.

But sometimes the condition doesnt exist, how can I procced?

Here the actual script part:

```
SQL.execute("SELECT CodePro FROM Table WHERE CodeID = ?", x)
CodePro = SQL.fetchone()[0]
```

but when no value is returned, the follow error is printed

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

Whatever library you use to execute the SQL statements should have a way to distinguish between an empty result set and one with one or more rows. Check a [tutorial for pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted). Something like this will work:

```
SQL.execute("SELECT CodePro FROM Table WHERE CodeID = ?", x)
row = SQL.fetchone()
if row:                        # check if there was at least one row returned
    CodePro = row[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL.execute("SELECT CodePro FROM Table WHERE CodeID = ?", x)
try:
    CodePro = SQL.fetchone()[0]
except:
    # Your exit here
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can modify the SQL to avoid the Null result。

such as in SQLServer, use this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CodePro,-1) FROM Table WHERE CodeID = ?
```

it will return -1 if CodePro is Null.

to know more about COALESCE: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, but a result set with one row with `NULL` is different that an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to surround it with a try/except, and have the "except" set CodePro to a value that lets you know it didn't find anything (ex: -1).